# R - Subset dataframe to include only subjects with more than 1 record

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, subset

I'd like to subset a dataframe to include all records for subjects that have >1 record, and exclude those subjects with only 1 record.

Let's take the following dataframe;

```
mydata <- data.frame(subject_id = factor(c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,9,10)),
                     variable = rnorm(15))
```

The code below gives me the subjects with >1 record using duplicated();

```
duplicates <- mydata[duplicated(mydata$subject_id),]$subject_id
```

But I want to retain in my subset **all** records for each subject with >1 record, so I tried;

```
mydata[mydata$subject_id==as.factor(duplicates),]
```

Which does not return the result I'm expecting.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) use something like `as.data.frame(cbind(... ))`. Just use `data.frame(var1 = ..., var2 = ...)` (see my edit of your question). This way, you'll also avoid creating many objects like subject_id and variable floating around in your global environment although you only want them in your data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple alternative is to use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dfr <- data.frame(a=sample(1:2,10,rep=T), b=sample(1:5,10, rep=T))
dfr <- group_by(dfr, b)
dfr
# Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
# Groups: b
# 
#    a b
# 1  2 4
# 2  2 2
# 3  2 5
# 4  2 1
# 5  1 2
# 6  1 3
# 7  2 1
# 8  2 4
# 9  1 4
# 10 2 4
filter(dfr, n() > 1)
# Source: local data frame [8 x 2]
# Groups: b
# 
#   a b
# 1 2 4
# 2 2 2
# 3 2 1
# 4 1 2
# 5 2 1
# 6 2 4
# 7 1 4
# 8 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks. All answers worked, but I felt this and the data.table solution are the most generalizable to other problems.  I chose this one b/c it allows me to continue working with the data a a data.frame rather than a data.table.

Answer (score 2):

A data.table solution

```
set.seed(20)
subject_id <- as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,9,10))
variable <- rnorm(15)
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(subject_id, variable))

library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, .SD[.N > 1], by = subject_id] # @Thanks David.
#    subject_id   variable
# 1:          4 -1.3325937
# 2:          4 -0.4465668
# 3:          5  0.5696061
# 4:          5 -2.8897176
# 5:          6 -0.8690183
# 6:          6 -0.4617027
# 7:          9 -0.1503822
# 8:          9 -0.6281268
# 9:          9  1.3232209
```

Comment: I think it should be `setDT(mydata)[, .SD[.N > 1], by = subject_id]`, because if there are more than one column, you will need specify them by hand with your method

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit your data frame a little bit:

```
set.seed(20)
subject_id <- as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,9,10))
variable <- rnorm(15)
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(subject_id, variable))
```

Now to get all the rows for subjects that appear more than once:

```
mydata[duplicated(mydata$subject_id) 
       | duplicated(mydata$subject_id, fromLast = TRUE), ]
#    subject_id   variable
# 4           4 -1.3325937
# 5           4 -0.4465668
# 6           5  0.5696061
# 7           5 -2.8897176
# 8           6 -0.8690183
# 9           6 -0.4617027
# 12          9 -0.1503822
# 13          9 -0.6281268
# 14          9  1.3232209
```

Edit: this would also work, using your `duplicates` vector:

```
mydata[mydata$subject_id %in% duplicates, ]
```

Comment: This works, and looking at what argument 'fromLast= TRUE' returns and reviewing the help file again, I believe I understand why. I hadn't thought about what "duplicated() determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of elements **with smaller subscripts**" from the help file meant.  Do you know of a function that would identify duplicates in a vector irregardless of position in index?

Comment: Thanks!  Your edit using my duplicates vector was the solution I was looking for. Although with several other answers now provided I see using {dplyr} or {data.table} is a more elegant way to accomplish this, so will select one of these as the answer for the benefit of other readers

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you go (I changed your variable to var <- rnorm(15):


set.seed(11)

subject_id<-as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,9,10))
var<-rnorm(15)
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(subject_id,var))

x1 <- c(names(table(mydata$subject_id)[table(mydata$subject_id) > 1]))
x2 <- which(mydata$subject_id %in% x1)
mydata[x2,]

     subject_id   var
4           4  0.3951076
5           4 -2.4129058
6           5 -1.3309979
7           5 -1.7354382
8           6  0.4020871
9           6  0.4628287
12          9 -2.1744466
13          9  0.4857337
14          9  1.0245632
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> mydata[mydata$subject_id %in% mydata[duplicated(mydata$subject_id),]$subject_id,]
   subject_id   variable
4           4 -1.3325937
5           4 -0.4465668
6           5  0.5696061
7           5 -2.8897176
8           6 -0.8690183
9           6 -0.4617027
12          9 -0.1503822
13          9 -0.6281268
14          9  1.3232209
```

Comment: Thanks, This works and is essentially what @Kara Woo added in her edit